# Why is xpath selecting whitespaces?

Tags: javascript, xpath

I have an XML list of countries as follows:

```
<countries>
  <country>
    <code>CA</code>
    <country>Canada</country>
  </country>
  ... etc...
</countries>
```

I want to select the nodes and iterate across them so use

```
path "/countries/*"
```

and then in JavaScript:

```
nodes = xml.evaluate(path, xml, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
```

When I iterate I find the first and 3rd nodes are whitespace (line feeds), the 2nd and 4th nodes are the actual XML I want.

How can I use XPath to ignore the whitespace nodes?  I'm only interested in the XML parts and I can't guarantee that the XML would contain line feeds.

Comment: Why can't you just use `//country`?

Comment: How would that work? it's a list of "countries".

Comment: Sorry I put Java in there by mistake. This is client side using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you use a simple program like this?

```
NodeList countries = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("//countries/country",
    builder.parse(inputStream),
    XPathConstants.NODESET);

for (int i = 0; i < countries.getLength(); i++) {
    Node country = notes.item(i);
    String code = (String) xpath.evaluate("./code/text()", country,
        XPathConstants.STRING);
    String name = (String) xpath.evaluate("./country/text()", country, 
        XPathConstants.STRING);

    System.out.println(String.format("%s has country code %s", name, code));
}
```

which with the input

```
<countries>
  <country>
    <code>CA</code>
    <country>Canada</country>
  </country>
  <country>
    <code>FR</code>
    <country>France</country>
  </country>
  <country>
    <code>IT</code>
    <country>Italy</country>
  </country>
  <country>
    <code>US</code>
    <country>United States</country>
  </country>
</countries>
```

outputs

```
Canada has country code CA
France has country code FR
Italy has country code IT
United States has country code US
```

Comment: Yeah that's Java though. I need to do this on the client with JavaScript.  I'm just trying to not select the line feeds as nodes.

Comment: You can easily translate to Javascript. Remember that if you select //countries/* you get all the children nodes, both dom element and text nodes (the line feeds you mention). If you are interested in the top-level country element, I can't understand what's wrong with //countries/country as per my example.

Comment: Yes thanks. You're right. select * includes the whitespaces but if I just select the nodes by name as you specified then it works fine. Thanks.

Comment: What you are describing is as if you used the XPath `/countries/node()`.  `*` should only match elements and would not return `text()` nodes. `/countries/*` and `/countries/country` should return the same set of elements for the example xml.

Comment: @MadsHansen you seem right. So what's wrong with his original code?

Comment: It may be that @Dan Howard was selecting the `country` elements correctly, but was then selecting it's  `node()` children, which include the `code` and `country` elements as well as whitespace only `text()` nodes.  The first child node of the `country` element would be whitespace-only `text()`, the second would be the `code` element,  etc.

Comment: Makes sense, even if we should then assume that the posted XPath is right, and the non posted one is wrong :P It requires intuition, experience and a little bit of imagination to find, but I think your assumptions can explain everything